# Proof Verification of Prob. 8, Chap 3 in Baby Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

The problem is if $\sum a_n $ converges, and if $\{ b_n \}$ is bounded and monotonic then prove that $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

I recently attempted this problem and came up with a solution which I don't think is as good as other solutions/proofs here, but i want to know if it's correct or not. So here is my solution :

According to the hypothesis $\sum a_n$ converges and $\{b_n\}$ is bounded & monotonic. So there exists $T,M \gt 0$ such that $|A_n| = \left|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k\right| \le M$ and $|b_n| \le T$.

For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists an $N_1 \gt 0$ such that $N_1 \le p \le q$ implies $\left|\displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n \right| \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{2T} \tag 1$

and again for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists an $N_2 \gt 0$ such that $N_2 \le p \le q$ implies $|b_p - b_q| \le \dfrac{\epsilon}{4M} \tag2.$

$N = \text{max}(N_1, N_2)$

$\begin{align}
 \left|\displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} c_n\right| = \left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n 
 b_n \right| 
 &= \left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q-1}A_n(b_n-b_{n+1}) + A_q b_q - A_{p-1} 
 b_p\right| \\
 &= \left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q-1}A_n(b_n-b_{n+1}) + A_q(b_q - b_p) - (A_{p-1} - 
 A_q)b_p \right| \\
 &\le M\left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q-1}(b_n-b_{n+1}) \right| + M\left| b_q - b_p 
 \right| + T\left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n \right| \\
 &= 2M\left| b_q - b_p \right| + T\left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n \right| \\
 &\le 2M\left( \dfrac{\epsilon}{4M} \right) + T\left( \dfrac{\epsilon}{2T} \right) = 
 \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + 
 \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon 
\end{align}$

So basically this mean that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an $N \gt 0$ such that $N \le p \le q$ implies $\left| \displaystyle\sum_{n=p}^{q} a_n 
 b_n \right| \le \epsilon.$

I am quite confident that this might be correct but I am not sure enough. Can somebody verify if it's correct or not ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to assume WLOG that $b_n$ is increasing, then show that $\sum_n a_nB$ converges where $B=\sup_n b_n$?

Comment: what is $B = \sup_n b_n$ ? And can you please verify the above proof ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\sup$? If not, you must be skipping parts of the book...

Comment: @Math1000 I am not skipping anything and I thought $\sup_n$ was something different than $\sup$. Never came across $\sup$ with a subscript $n$

Comment: $\sup_n b_n = \sup\{b_n: n\in\mathbb N\}$. That is all.